# How to change the color of a single Icon in a FlatList without having them all change at the same time

Tags: react-native

I have a FlatList with menu items and im trying to make it so when a menu item is selected, the little plus icon lights up green. However currently when a item is selected they all light up green together and all turn off together when one is deselected

Ive tried using the useState hook, but im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
const [menuIsSelect, setMenuIsSelect] = useState(false);

const BusinessMenu = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList 
        data = {props.data} 
        keyExtractor = {(key) => props.data.name}
        renderItem = {itemData => 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => setMenuIsSelect(!menuIsSelect)}>
                <View style = {styles.menuItem}>
                    <Ionicons name = 'ios-add-circle-outline' size = {15} color = {menuIsSelect ? Colors.themeColor : 'black'} />
                    <Text style = {styles.Name}>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.price}>{itemData.item.price}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
    />
    );
};
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution provided by Sunny Shah was almost right.

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState([]);
const BusinessMenu = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data = {props.data} 
            keyExtractor = {(key) => props.data.name}
            extraData={selectedIndex}
            renderItem = {(index) => 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=> selectItem(index)}>
                    <View style = {styles.menuItem}>
                        <Ionicons name = 'ios-add-circle-outline' size = {15} color = {selectedIndex.indexOf(index)>-1  ? Colors.themeColor : 'black'} />
                        <Text style = {styles.Name}>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                        <Text style = {styles.price}>{itemData.item.price}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        />
    );
};

const selectItem = (index) => {
if(selectedIndex.indexOf(index)>-1){
  let newArray = selectedIndex.filter((indexObject)=>{
    if(indexObject == index){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
})
setSelectedIndex(newArray);
}else{
setSelectedIndex([
    ...selectedIndex,index
  ]);
}

};
```

This originally did not work. So i decided to add an `id:` in my structure which just corresponded to the array index of the object. Originally it was just `name:` and `price:`

```
[ {
id: '0', 
name : 'Chicken',
price : 20
}, {
id: '1' ,
name: 'Beef', 
price: 30
}, {
id: '2', 
name: 'Seafood',
price: 10
} ]
```

Then i made three changes.

1. in my `renderItem` for my `FlatList` I just used `(itemData)` and not `index`.
2. For my Touchable Opacity I used `onPress = {() => SelectItem(itemData.item.id)}`
3. For my Ionicons color prop I used `color = {selectedIndex.indexOf(itemData.item.id) > -1 ? Colors.themeColor : 'black'`

Im not sure why this worked because my id's is literally just the array index. But im just happy that it did :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use array to identify which item has been selected or not;

First create array

```
     const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState([]);
```

On select call handle row selection

```
<FlatList 
        data = {props.data} 
        keyExtractor = {(key) => props.data.name}
        extraData={selectedIndex}
        renderItem = {(index) => 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=> selectItem(index)}>
                <View style = {styles.menuItem}>
                    <Ionicons name = 'ios-add-circle-outline' size = {15} color = {selectedIndex.indexOf(index)>-1  ? Colors.themeColor : 'black'} />
                    <Text style = {styles.Name}>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.price}>{itemData.item.price}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
    />
```

On selectItem

```
const selectItem = (index) => {
   if(selectedIndex.indexOf(index)>-1){
      let newArray = selectedIndex.filter((indexObject)=>{
        if(indexObject == index){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
    setSelectedIndex(newArray);
   }else{
    setSelectedIndex([
        ...selectedIndex,index
      ]);
   }

  };
```

Make sure you add **extraData** on **FlatList** to update List

Comment: I did exactly what you said but they still all go green when i select an item. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the particular index of the item and then make the changes you want like changing the color. renderItem of Flatlist second argument provides you the index which you can access to have the notice of particular item present at an particular index.
//Map the index of the data set to the index of flatlist.

```
const [menuIsSelect, setMenuIsSelect] = useState(false);

const BusinessMenu = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList 
        data = {props.data} 
        keyExtractor = {(key) => props.data.name}
        renderItem = {(itemData,index) => 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => setMenuIsSelect(!menuIsSelect)}>
                <View style = {styles.menuItem}>
                    <Ionicons name = 'ios-add-circle-outline' size = {15} color = {menuIsSelect ? Colors.themeColor : 'black'} />
                    <Text style = {styles.Name}>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.price}>{itemData.item.price}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
    />
    );
};
```

The line : `<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => setMenuIsSelect(!menuIsSelect)}>` is causing the issue. You have to access a particular element of flatlist which can be accessed by using `itemData` this basically is the particular item which needs to be changed.

Comment: How can i use the second argument 'index' of renderItem? I'm not sure what you mean when you say "you can access to have the notice of particular item present at an particular index"

Answer (score 0):

An attempt of solution is to do something like :

- it is better to use **menuIsSelect** in the state of each item menu to avoid sharing the same state for all your item component. That's why all your components change with the same color.
- it's better to use PureComponent for your item list for performance.

```
const setMenuIsSelect = (selectedItem) => {
    //...
}

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
       <MenuItem 
            menu={item}
            setMenuIsSelect={setMenuIsSelect}
        />
);

const BusinessMenu = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data = {props.data} 
            keyExtractor = {(key) => props.data.name}
            renderItem = {renderItem}
        />
    );
};

// ----------------------------------------

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MenuItem extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        menuIsSelect: false
    };

    handleToggleSelect = (item) => {
        const { setMenuIsSelect } = this.props;

        this.setState({
            menuIsSelect: !this.state.menuIsSelect
        }, () => {
            setMenuIsSelect(this.state.menuIsSelect ? item : null);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {menuIsSelect} = this.state;
        const {menu} = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.handleToggleSelect(menu)}>
                <View style = {styles.menuItem}>
                    <Ionicons name = 'ios-add-circle-outline' size = {15} color = {menuIsSelect ? Colors.themeColor : 'black'} />
                    <Text style = {styles.Name}>{menu.name}</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.price}>{menu.price}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

}
```